# Search data structure that doesn't support deletion

Tags: performance, data-structures, time-complexity

My collection holds millions of key-value pairs and supports:

- insertion
- search
- inorder traversal
- space complexity is *O(n)*

Currently I use an AVL tree but I noticed there are no deletions during the lifetime of collection (let's say any memory the collection allocates will be bulk-freed by the heap manager at no cost).

Are there search data structures that perform better than usual RB or AVL trees with a drawback of being unable (or ineffective) to delete already inserted data?

Comment: There is nothing better than a tree for that in term of complexity (and this can be quite easily proven). That being said some tree can be faster than others regarding the ratio of insert/search/traversal. B-tree for example are generally pretty good for large trees: they are compact and cache efficient. The insertion can be a bit slower though (but not so for large trees).  The traversal should be significantly faster. The deletion do not add a significant overhead in the design of trees, the load balancing is the main issue (so the mutation of the tree is the main issue not just deletions).

Comment: @JérômeRichard Yes, I suspected that trees are the best choice. But hopefully there is an exotic tree that does less rotations or has better max height than AVL tree.

Comment: [Skip list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list) has the same asymptotic complexity as a tree and often has better real-time performance. Implementation effort is similar. Skip list supports the four operations that you mention.

Comment: @JimMischel we use skip lists extensively but they excel only if the collection is concurrent, otherwise they are 20-50% slower compared to AVL trees.